# Spring Data JPA Multiple DataSources - CockroachDb Spatial

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spatial, cockroachdb

My application has two data sources.
First datasource access Postgre using JdbcTemplate.
Second datasource access CockroachDb using Spring Data JPA.

So i created two configurations for this datasources.

Persisting to both datasources works fine, except objects with spatial data.
When i trying to save spatial data to CockroachDb, i get an error:

> Hibernate: select geoobject0_.id as id1_2_0_, geoobject0_.address as
> address2_2_0_, geoobject0_.address_id as address_3_2_0_,
> geoobject0_.created as created4_2_0_, geoobject0_.flat_count as
> flat_cou5_2_0_, geoobject0_.geo_provider_id as geo_prov6_2_0_,
> geoobject0_.geometry as geometry7_2_0_, geoobject0_.hq_id as
> hq_id8_2_0_, geoobject0_.is_generated as is_gener9_2_0_,
> geoobject0_.is_living as is_livi10_2_0_, geoobject0_.payload as
> payload11_2_0_, geoobject0_.source_id as source_12_2_0_,
> geoobject0_.type as type13_2_0_, geoobject0_.uic_id as uic_id14_2_0_,
> geoobject0_.version_id as version15_2_0_, geoobject0_.voter_count as
> voter_c16_2_0_ from geo_service.geo_object geoobject0_ where
> geoobject0_.id=? Hibernate: insert into geo_service.geo_object
> (address, address_id, created, flat_count, geo_provider_id, geometry,
> hq_id, is_generated, is_living, payload, source_id, type, uic_id,
> version_id, voter_count, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,
> ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) 2022-01-18 17:01:39.583
> [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] WARN
> o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions() - SQL Error: 0,
> SQLState: XXUUU  2022-01-18 17:01:39.584
> [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] ERROR
> o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions() - ERROR: wkb:
> unknown byte order: 10101100

Java configuration:

For Postgre:

```
@Configuration
public class UicDbConfig {

    @Bean(name = "uicDataSource")
    @Qualifier("uicDataSource")
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.uic.datasource")
    public DataSource secondaryDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }
}
```

For CockroachDb:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "ru.stimul.geoservice.repo",
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "primaryEntityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "primaryTransactionManager")
public class CockroachDbConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean("primaryDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.primary.datasource")
    public DataSource primaryDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "primaryEntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean primaryEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder
            ,@Qualifier("primaryDataSource") DataSource primaryDataSource){

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = builder
                .dataSource(primaryDataSource)
                .packages("ru.stimul.geoservice.domain.primary")
                .persistenceUnit("domains")
                .build();

        final HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        em.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());

        return em;

    }

    @Bean(name = "primaryTransactionManager")
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager(@Qualifier("primaryEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory primaryEntityManagerFactory){
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(primaryEntityManagerFactory);

        return transactionManager;
    }


    private Properties additionalProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("spring.primary.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect"));
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", env.getProperty("spring.primary.jpa.show-sql"));
        return properties;
    }
}
```

application.yml:

```
spring:
  application.name: geo-service
  http:
    encoding:
      charset: UTF-8
      enabled: true
  main:
    allow-bean-definition-overriding: true

  primary:
    datasource:
      jdbcUrl: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:26257/geo_service
      driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver
      username: admin
      password: 
    jpa:
      show-sql: true
      hibernate:
        ddl-auto: none
      properties:
        hibernate:
          dialect: org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.cockroachdb.CockroachDB202SpatialDialect
      generate-ddl: false

  uic:
    datasource:
      jdbc-url: "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:2222/uic"
      driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver
      username: postgres
      password: 
      schema: 
      hikari:
        connectionTimeout: 20000
        maximumPoolSize: 10
      max-active: 3
      initial-size: 1
      max-idle: 2
      min-idle: 1
      test-while-idle: true
      test-on-borrow: true
      max-idle-time: 160000
      max-lifetime: 0
```

Domain object:

```
import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Point;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import ru.stimul.geoservice.Geo;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Data
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "geo_object", schema = "geo_service")
@Slf4j
public class GeoObject {

    @Id
    @Column
    String id;

    @Column
    Long created;

    @Column(name = "version_id")
    String versionId;

    @Column(name = "hq_id")
    String hqId;

    @Column(name = "source_id")
    String sourceId;

    @Column(name = "geo_provider_id")
    String geoProviderId;

    @Column(name = "uic_id")
    String uicId;

    @Column(name = "address_id")
    String addressId;

    Point geometry;

    @Column
    String address;

    @Column
    String type;

    @Column(name = "flat_count")
    Long flatCount;

    @Column(name = "voter_count")
    Long voterCount;

    @Column(name = "is_living")
    boolean isLiving;

    @Column(name = "is_generated")
    boolean isGenerated;

    @Column(length = 2000)
    String payload;
}
```

Repository:

```
package ru.stimul.geoservice.repo;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import ru.stimul.geoservice.domain.primary.GeoObject;

@Repository
public interface CockroachDbRepository extends JpaRepository<GeoObject, String> {
}
```

Service:

```
public GeoObject upsertWithoutAccessCheck(String requestId, GeoObject geoObject) {
        if (Objects.isNull(geoObject.getId()) || StringUtils.isEmpty(geoObject.getId())) {
            geoObject = geoObject.toBuilder()
                    .id(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                    .build();
        }
        return cockroachDbRepository.saveAndFlush(geoObject);
}
```

pom.xml:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.33.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-spatial</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.33.Final</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Resolved changing com.vividsolutions to org.locationtech https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62877520/unable-to-make-geospatial-query-within-with-spring-boot-spring-data-jpa-and-h

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to you use Hikari to handle multiple datasources.

```
    @Configuration
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "first.datasource")
    @EnableTransactionManagement
    public class FirstDBConfig extends HikariConfig {
    
        @Bean
        public DataSource firstDataSource() {
            return new HikariDataSource(this);
        }
    ...........................................
    
    @Configuration
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "second.datasource")
    @EnableTransactionManagement
    @EnableJpaRepositories( basePackages = {
                "com.myproyect.repos"
        },
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "myEntityManager",
        transactionManagerRef = "myTransactionManager")
    public class SecondDBConfig extends HikariConfig {
    
        @Bean
        public DataSource secondDataSource() {
            return new HikariDataSource(this);
        }
```

For more detail read about hikari

https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP#readme